# What is the Pseudo-Hillbert curve equivalent for hexogonal and triangular tesselations?

Tags: tesselation, space-filling-curve

Triangles, squares and hexagons can all be used to fill a surface (tessellation).

For now let's assume the surface has a limited number of tiles (triangles, squares or hexagons)

The goal is to define a line that touches each tile so that points that are close to each other or the line (1D) are also close to each other on the surface (2D).

The solution for a square based tesselation you have the (Pseudo)-Hillbert curve. Below is an example of a second order pseado-hillbert curve.

[image]

Explained in this fantastic [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s7h2MHQtxc)

I was wondering what the equivalent (if any) of the pseudo-hillbert curve for tesselations based on triangles or hexagons are. I am looking for a full tesselation so no holes as in a Sierpinsky Triangle.

I found this great [resource](https://spacefillingcurves.wordpress.com/category/hilbert-curve/)

And for [triangles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_8xllwFHLs) using a Peano curve.

[image]

Comment: Also looking for an answer